# Retorno dos botões

Tags: javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, onde há 40 botões de ligar e desligar.

São botões do tipo 'switch' e a estrutura de todos são a mesma, segue abaixo:

```
<div class="item">
    <strong>04</strong><br>
    <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id='meu_checkbox' onclick='enviar()'>
    <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
 </div>
```

Em cada um destes botões, é 'puxado' um script JS que retorna uma URL ao ligar e outra ao desligar o botão. Segue abaixo:

```
function enviar(){
  const checkbox = document.getElementById('meu_checkbox');
  if(checkbox.checked === true){
     checkbox.checked = true;
     console.log('http://localhost/RH1');
  }else{
     checkbox.checked = false;
     console.log('http://localhost/RH2');
  }
}
```

Ao executar este código ele retorna no botão 01 corretamente cada URL ao ligar e ao desligar, contudo nos outros botões ele aplica apenas a segunda opção.

Se puderem me auxiliar no motivo que isto ocorre, pois mesmo pesquisando sobre o assunto e mudando diversas vezes o código não consegui fazê-lo ter o comportamento correto.

[Retorno do primeiro botão](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEIz3.png)

[Retorno dos demais botões](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKWn5.png)

Comment: a função enviar pega o elemento com id "meu_checkbox", como o Id é sempre único no html, se o código estiver assim não vai funcionar, pq se tem vários "botões", cada um deve ter um Id diferente, e obviamente, uma função diferente, como nome diferente, não me parece que é assim que está o código, logo não vai funcionar bem

Comment: @RicardoPontual Pode por gentileza me auxiliar em como eu faço para adicionar corretamente a função em todos os botões? Eu achava que ao acrescentar o onclick em todos, funcionaria, uma vez que todos possuem a mesma estrutura.

Comment: faltam detalhes na sua pergunta para entender o que pretende... se a url for sempre a mesma faça o seguinte: 1) remova o id, ou use ids diferentes 2) ao chamar a função, passe "o próprio elemento" usando *this*, assim não precisa pegar pelo id, assim: `onclick='enviar(this)'` 3) remova a linha com a `const checkbox`, e receba diretamente isso na função, assim `function enviar(checkbox){`, assim o *click* passa para a função, usando o *this*, qual foi o botão que foi clicado, veja se isso já te resolve

Comment: Tentei realizar estas correções e gerou um erro informando que checkbox não está definido. Pode por gentileza me exemplificar como seria o correto?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muito procurar na internet, encontrei uma forma que funciona corretamente o código em todos os botões, segue abaixo:

No HTML, é preciso definir o evento onclick com this, pois assim ele irá referenciar o elemento da minha função enviar.

```
<div class="item">
    <strong>04</strong><br>
    <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id='meu_checkbox' onclick='enviar(this)'>
    <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

No JS, ao invés de definir uma variável checkbox "fixa", defino na função a chamada do meu ID 'meu_checkbox', com element, para que sempre que ele encontrar por este ID, ele retornará a função no onclick.

```
function enviar(element){
  if(element.checked === true){
     element.checked = true;
     console.log('http://localhost/RH1');
  }else{
     element.checked = false;
     console.log('http://localhost/RH2');
  }
}
```